# How to get first 8 components from PCA using pcromp package?

Tags: r, prcomp

I am implementing a PCA using prcomp.

```
pcaunemp <- prcomp(rawtChange,center = TRUE, scale=FALSE)
```

I am using the lm function for regression like so:

```
reg <- lm(tr[5:365,1] ~ tr[1:361,1] + tr[2:362,1] + tr[3:363,1] + tr[4:364,1])
```

If I want to only use the first 8 components as independent variables for a regression, how do I extract the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can extract first 8 PCs with:

```
pcaunemp$x[, 1:8]
```

Credits to 李哲源 who answered in the comments